# Where to find php_printer.dll?

Tags: php, dll

I have a class that makes use of the php_printer extension but I can't find it anywhere and at php.net it says it's currently unavailable. I googled it, but all I downloaded from other sites was not efficient. It seemed to me it was outdated. I copied the .dll file in the extensions folder and set the configuration in php.ini but I still couldn't use its built-in functions.I have PHP  5.3.1 installed.

Comment: What does this class actually *do*? Is there something else you could use instead?

Comment: @DaveRandom the class prints a file to a network printer directly through PHP

Comment: @menislici do u have this extension for any latest php version (greater than 7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then you did not google very well. There still are repositories of precompiled binaries elsewhere:

- https://github.com/maryo/php-5.5-windows-extensions
- http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/printer/0.1.0-dev/
- <s>http://downloads.php.net/pierre/</s>

Just saying it does not work is insufficient. I understand that compiling from source is effortful on Windows (`pecl install printer` given a proper compiler setup), but at the very least run the PHP interpreter on the commandline after editing the `php.ini`. It would give you a useful error message in case of linking errors, or none in case you edited the wrong config file. (Too few details to answer.)

See also: [PHP 5.4.7 Compiling ext php_printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776490/php-5-4-7-compiling-ext-php-printer)

Comment: I love hyperlinks: `Not Found

The requested URL /~pierre/ was not found on this server.`

Answer (score 2):

download and unzip the extenssions file
http://museum.php.net/php5/pecl-5.2.6-nts-Win32.zip

Answer (score 0):

http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ appears to have one that dates to 2010.

I'd consider looking for some other solution though, it doesn't look like a very widely supported extension and it's not been updated for at least a year.