# Print directly to printer using PHP

Tags: dll, printing, php, php-extension

I want to send text files to the print directly from PHP script (for example print a receipt after I have inserted records to my DB).

Is this possible using `php_printer.dll`?

I have tried to install this extension (in `php.ini`), but I get errors. Is this extension available with PHP 5.3.x?

Is any other way?

Comment: Printer of the user over a web browser, or a printer connected to the server?

Comment: Printer connected to the server

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried to install this extension (in php.ini), but I get errors. Is this extension available with PHP 5.3.x?

I can not tell you that, but even if it is, that information is probably useless for you because you did not manage to install it in the first place. So how should answering that question make a difference? You can find out more if something is available here: [Where to find php_printer.dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916480/where-to-find-php-printer-dll)

> Is any other way?

Generate a PDF. Store it. Pipe it to a program that turns it into a postscript file. Pipe that postscript to a postscript capable printer. Job done.