# PHP 5.4.7 Compiling ext php_printer

Tags: php, dll, printing, compilation

My Knowledge base is, I can get around in php. I never worked with C, C++, C# or any compilers.

I Upgraded from XAMPP 1.7.3, which used php 5.3, to 1.8.1 which includes:
Apache 2.4.3
MySQL 5.5.27
PHP 5.4.7

It is being installed on Windows 7 Pro, Windows XP Pro and Windows Server 2008 r2. But I am trying to get it to working on Windows 7 currently.

I upgraded because I needed a newer version of Apache and MySQL for security reasons. I do not have the option to downgrade.

I use the php_printer.dll for the ability to print raw data to the printer:

```
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");
```

My Code worked fine in PHP 5.3 but broke in PHP 5.4.

After receiving the error: " Fatal error: Call to undefined function printer_open() in ~". I checked the php_error_log and received the following information.

```
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: printer: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
```

I've looked for hours trying to find a pre-compiled php_printer.dll for PHP 5.4.7 to no avail. I have concluded that I will have to compile it from source files in the PECL. pecl.php.net/package/printer

Having never had to do this before I did what any internet user should do. I googled it and found some information here:
https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild

It took me all day but the PHP build worked. But then tried to create the php_printer.dll
First I tried :

```
svn co http://svn.php.net/repository/pecl/printer/trunk pecl/printer
```

But it said: 
    'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

So I just downloaded the files myself from:
**svn.php.net/repository/pecl/printer/trunk/**
and put them in:
**C:\php-sdk\php54dev\vc9\x86\php5.4-201303311430\ext\printer**

I made sure to download the libraries both from:
**windows.php.net/downloads/php-sdk/deps/vc9/x86/**
Also just the:
**deps-5.4-vc9-x86.7z**

I tried one then the other, however; every time I received the following when I tried to nmake:

```
c:\php-sdk\php54dev\vc9\x86\php5.4-201303311430>nmake

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 9.00.30729.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

printer.c
ext\printer\printer.c(266) : error C2065: 'pval' : undeclared identifier
```

---

UPDATE

I got some help on another forum.

---

by hackattack142 » 03. April 2013 23:51

Hello,

Open 'printer.c' and replace all instances of 'pval' with 'zval' and it should compile.

---

Thank you Hackattack, one step closer I hope,

```
c:\php-sdk\php54dev\vc9\x86\php5.4-201303311430>buildconf
~
c:\php-sdk\php54dev\vc9\x86\php5.4-201303311430>configure --disable-all --enable-cli 
--enable-printer
~
c:\php-sdk\php54dev\vc9\x86\php5.4-201303311430>nmake

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 9.00.30729.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

internal_functions.c
printer.c
   Creating library Release_TS\php5ts.lib and object Release_TS\php5ts.exp
   Creating library Release_TS\php.lib and object Release_TS\php.exp
SAPI sapi\cli build complete
```

It seemed to have compiled. However; I can't find a printer.dll or a php_printer.dll which is the outcome I was hoping for.

In the **Release_TS\ext** folder there is a folder named **Printer**. It contains the following Files:
**printer.obj
printer.sbr
vc90.idb**

I also did the last step:

```
c:\php-sdk\php54dev\vc9\x86\php5.4-201303311430>cd Release_TS
c:\php-sdk\php54dev\vc9\x86\php5.4-201303311430\Release_TS>php -m
[PHP Modules]
Core
date
ereg
pcre
printer
Reflection
SPL
standard
[Zend Modules]
c:\php-sdk\php54dev\vc9\x86\php5.4-201303311430\Release_TS>
```

---

Help from another forum

```
configure --disable-all --enable-cli --enable-printer=shared
```

It worked and i created the php_printer.dll however when i tried to use it:

In PHP Error Log:
[15-Apr-2013 15:34:53 UTC] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'php_printer.dll' in Unknown on line 0

---

I had to grab 5.4.7 files as I was using 5.4.15 but XAMPP 1.8.1 uses 5.4.7

http://www.oldapps.com/php_programming_language.php?old_php=8227

And put it in: C:\php-sdk\php54dev\vc9\x86\php-5.4.7

then put the printer files in the ext folder and did all the above processes and:

configure --enable-printer=shared

**And it worked:**

**PHP Version 5.4.7 php_printer.dll**

**http://pylonx.com/PHP/php_printer_5.4.7.zip**

Comment: You've got no experience with C and you want to compile a PHP module - that's a big task. You've got no experience with C and you want to start compiling stuff on MS-Windows? That's almost funny. It will probably be quicker to rewrite the code to generate a PDF then print it via ghostscript.

Comment: Yup! Well, the problem is the printers we are using have their own language. So I have to send the print to them in their code, not a PDF.

Comment: Additionally, I was hoping that all I would need to do is compile the already built C code which was available via the PECL.

Comment: I hope u can share ur newst php_printer.dll fir php 5.4 :D

Comment: Got mine working. Hope this trial and error mess helps someone. Also, posted the 5.4.7 php_printer.dll for others to use. But you should be able to build your own.

Comment: @dBaker if you solved your problem post ur solution as an answer. yup u can answer ur own question and accept it ;)

Comment: You deserve a badge! As @symcbean said, that is a hard task and you seem to have accomplished it! WOW!
Also, post your solution as a separate post and accept it!

Comment: dBaker, we've been searching for weeks for a version that will run and have decided to follow your journey, thanks a million man, you deserve a medal

Answer (score 2):

Download and install any version of php you like and install the appropriate php printer dll here: http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/printer/0.1.0-dev/

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in versions 5.4.7 to 5.4.11 of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use xampp 1.6.8 version it will fix these issues. it has php 5.2.6 and also php_printer.dll file has saved in ext folder in php folder. so you will only have to un-comment the line extension=php_printer.dll in php.ini file which noticed in the path under "Loaded Configuration File" section on php info page.
you can find that version of xamppfrom oldapps.com