# Is there php7 printer extension/dll?

Tags: php, printing

Is there any printer extension for php 7 ? Or can someone provide working solution how to print form php? Or I should use sockets for that ? I tried dll from 5.6 but it doesnt work(

Comment: If using a Unix-flavored operating system then you can install [CUPS](https://www.cups.org/) on your PHP server, install a printer, and issue `exec('lpr -P printer_name /path/to/filename.txt');`

Comment: lpr is [also available for windows](https://www.itg.ias.edu/content/connect-network-printer-lpr-windows7)

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of stuff to be done to make its source code available for build into an usable extension besides [the common tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776490/php-5-4-7-compiling-ext-php-printer). There are [some replacements](http://www.sklar.com/software/php/2015/03/23/converting-a-php-extension-to-php-7/) that can be done and other issues involve finding what to do with no longer used variables and currently invalid syntax. It's a a very outdated, yet usefull extension. I've also tried to do it myself with no success ([it builds but it doesn't work](https://github.com/laeirbag/StuffToShare)).

The easiest way I found and still use in POS (receipt) Printers is just a

```
system("(echo ".$TextToBePrinted.") >\\\\MachineNameOrPreferablyFixedIp\\PrinterNetworkName");
```

Every time a new line is needed. Null and newLine characters are indeed possible to send in a single command containing whole custom text, but it's very fastidious. For the same kind of printers there is [esc-pos php library](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php) available.

**Note:** No matter if it is a local printer, it has to be shared and better if used as "\\127.0.0.1\PrinterNetworkName". PrinterNetworkName avoids invalid characters as same as in files, so "Generic / Text Only" has to be accessed as "\\127.0.0.1\Generic  Text Only".

Simmilar alternatives for common use printers include using [dosprn](http://www.dosprn.com/) and fwrite or, again,
`system("echo ...");`ing to COMn/LPTn faked or real ports or, if you don't care: create, write and `system("print ...");` file having correctly associated extension for the filename you gave.

And for the hardcord-ers, you can build a binary (.exe) to listen to a custom port or calling binary with `system(...);` directly and print. It's no so hard on c++ using boost. The real hardcore decision would be building a dll extension (By the way: C++ windows api contains simmilar functionality for printing like php does in its extension for managing paper and font size, style and so on).

PHP and dll's with different fisrt two numbers in version won't work. So stop trying to make it happen.

Comment: `fastidious` really? i would imagine all you need is `"echo ".escapeshellarg($text)`

Comment: Now Ｔｈａｔ's a usefull twist. Thank you!