# No php_printer at php.net anymore

Tags: php

Do anyone have php_printer.dll version? I had tried to find, but there is no working links on this dll. All links going to  php.net, pierre page, but it's not exist anymore.

Comment: Please take a look at the second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916480/where-to-find-php-printer-dll